# Display the same title text for all elements of the same class?

Tags: css, tooltip, html

Lets say I want to display tool tips for links using the `title` attribute:

```
   <a class="editcommand" title="Edit" ...>
```

Is there a way to specify the `title` text for all elements of the same class using CSS, so I don't have to repeat it within each element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS is only for the content of the style="" attribute, not other HTML tags. This sounds like a job for Javascript. If you're using jQuery here's an example:

`$('a').attr('title', 'My universal title');`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, CSS does not provide that ability. Since `title` is an HTML attribute (besides the `<title>` element of course), it's up to the markup structure (DOM) to define it, not the style (CSS).

With JavaScript it's just a matter of attaching the attribute to a set of DOM elements with that class. But again, that's modifying the DOM elements themselves, not their style properties.